# UiDatePicker Xcode 6 not showing current date in label and no done or cancel button

Tags: ios, ios8, datepicker, xcode6, uilabel

guys I can't seem to figure out how come when I have implemented the datepicker it does not allow to pick the current date. I also followed many answers here to show done button when the datepicker pops-up.

Kindly help me with the done button and the setting the label to the current date by default.

Here is my screenshot [image]

```
- (IBAction)btnDate:(id)sender {
datepicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 300)];
datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datepicker.hidden = NO;
datepicker.date = [NSDate date];

[datepicker addTarget:self
               action:@selector(LabelChange:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
datepicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:datepicker]; //this can set value of selected date to your label change according to your condition


NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"M-d-yyyy"]; // from here u can change format..
lblDate.text=[df stringFromDate:datepicker.date];
```

}

```
- (void)LabelChange:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"M-d-yyyy"];
    lblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [df stringFromDate:datepicker.date]];
    [datepicker removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: try to add UIButton as a subview to the datepicker like [datepicker addsubview:btn]

Comment: i tried and even copied and pasted this code from this blog tutorial [link]http://mkonstantinou.blogspot.com/2012/12/adding-done-button-to-uidatepicker.html but still not showing done and can't select current date.

Comment: Can you please post the code

Comment: Is exactly the same code as the link I shared

Comment: see the code snippet on the question

Comment: Where is your done button?

Comment: //calls DoneClicked
    UIBarButtonItem *bbitem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DoneClicked)];
    [itemsBar addObject:bbitem];
    [toolbarPicker setItems:itemsBar animated:YES];
    [pickerAction addSubview:toolbarPicker];
    [pickerAction addSubview:datePicker];
    [pickerAction showInView:self.view];
    [pickerAction setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70208/discussion-between-tensri-and-cockpit-aliens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question with this helpful tutorial. Here is the piece of code that someone may make use of if they want date picker with cancel and done button taken from the link below the snippet for more information and credits to the author.

```
/*
 * Change the date.
 */
- (void)changePickUpDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyyMMdd" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];

    NSString *todayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date];
    NSLog(@"todayString: %@", todayString);

    DateLabel.text =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", todayString]init];
    //NSLog(@"New Date: %@", sender.date);
}

/*
 * Releases the background, datepicker and toolbar.
 */
- (void)removeViews:(id)object {

    /*
     *  Releases the background view.
     */
    [[self.view viewWithTag:9] removeFromSuperview];
    /*
     *  Releases the datepicker.
     */
    [[self.view viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
    /*
     *  Releases the toolbar.
     */
    [[self.view viewWithTag:11] removeFromSuperview];
}

/*
 * Hides the datapicker.
 */
- (void)dismissDatePicker:(id)sender {

    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for hiding the toolbar.
     */
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44);
    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for hiding the datepicker.
     */
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height + 44, 320, 216);

    /*
     * Send start animation message to UIView.
     */
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveOut" context:nil];
    /*
     * Set the transparency for hiding the background view.
     */
    [self.view viewWithTag:9].alpha = 0;
    /*
     * Set the target position for hiding the datepicker.
     */
    [self.view viewWithTag:10].frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    /*
     * Set the target position for hiding the toolbar.
     */
    [self.view viewWithTag:11].frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    /*
     * The method setAnimationDelegate enables knowledge on start and end of the animation.
     */
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    /*
     * Calls the removeViews method at the end of the animation.
     */
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeViews:)];
    /*
     * Commits the animation thread for execution.
     */
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

/*
 * Sets up and shows the datepicker.
 */
- (IBAction)callPickUpDP {
    /*
     * If view with tag exists ignore the rest of the code and exit.
     */
    if([self.view viewWithTag:9]) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for showing the toolbar.
     */
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 216 - 44, 320, 44);
    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for showing the datepicker.
     */
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 216, 320, 216);

    /*
     * Instantiate a UIView with the frame size of the existing view.
     */
    UIView *darkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    /*
     * Set the transparency.
     */
    darkView.alpha = 0;
    /*
     * Set the background color.
     */
    darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    /*
     * Set a tag for the UIView instance to reference it by tag.
     */
    darkView.tag = 9;
    /*
     * Setup a tap gesture listener that calls the dismissDatePicker method on tap.
     */
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
    /*
     * Add the tap gesture listener to the UIView.
     */
    [darkView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    /*
     * Adds the subview on top of all the other subviews.
     */
    [self.view addSubview:darkView];

    /*
     * Instantiate a UIDatePicker and set the initial frame with the datepicker outside of the view.
     */

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)];
    /*
     * Set a tag for the UIDatePicker instance to reference it by tag.
     */

    datePicker.alpha = 1;
    datePicker.tag = 10;
    datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    /*
     * Add a listener that listens for changing values in the datepicker which then calls the change date method.
     */
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changePickUpDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    /*
     * Adds the subview on top of all the other subviews.
     */
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

    /*
     * Instantiate a UIToolbar and set the initial frame with the toolbar outside of the view.
     */
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
    /*
     * Set a tag for the UIToolbar instance to reference it by tag.
     */
    toolBar.tag = 11;
    /*
     * Set a style for the UIToolbar.
     */
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    /*
     * Instantiate a spacer UIBarButtonItem.
     */
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    /*
     * Instantiate a done UIBarButtonItem on click this will call the dismissDatePicker method.
     */
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
    /*
     * Set the created UIBarButtonItems to the toolbar.
     */
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
    /*
     * Adds the subview on top of all the other subviews.
     */
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

    /*
     * Start animation.
     */
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
    /*
     * Set the target position for showing the toolbar.
     */
    toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    /*
     * Set the target position for showing the datepicker.
     */
    datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    /*
     * Set the transparency for showing background view.
     */
    darkView.alpha = 0.5;
    /*
     * Commits the animation thread for execution.
     */
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

[iOS – How To Make DatePicker](http://team.158ltd.com/2013/12/21/ios-how-to-make-datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

try to use UITextField instead of UILabel with next code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // Create date picker

    UIDatePicker * datePicker = [UIDatePicker new];

    // Create and configure toolbar

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 44)];

    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(doneAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                  target:self
                                                                                  action:@selector(cancelAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                              target:nil
                                                                              action:nil];
    [toolbar setItems:@[cancelButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton]];

    // Set date picker as input view

    self.textField.inputView = datePicker;

    // Set toolbar as accessory view

    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
}

- (void)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker* datePicker = (UIDatePicker*)[self.textField inputView];
    self.textField.text = datePicker.date.description;
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)cancelAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

in this way, date picker will appear each time you hit the textField, or call `becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: I tried to change the button to UITextField, but have problem with, this crashes; Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

Comment: Please send me invite to the chat room.